# How do you go about creating a like button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am making a forum with Laravel and Vue.

When a user clicks a like button I wanna increment 1 and if he clicks it again I wanna decrement 1.

So far I have this view.

```
<span v-for="comment in comments">

        <p> @{{ comment.reply }}</p>
        <button @click="addLikes(comment.id,auth_id)" v-if="auth_id" v-show="!unlike">like</button>
        <button @click="unLike(comment.likes.!!HERE!!)" v-if="auth_id" v-show="unlike">unlike</button>
        <p>@{{ comment.likes.length }} likes</p>



        <div v-if="auth_id == comment.user_id">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" @click="showComment(comment.id)" >edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" @click="deleteComment(comment.id)">delete</button>
         </div>

    </span>
```

The thing is when a user clicks a button every like buttons turn into dislike buttons right?

How do you go about dealing with it?make a Vue component??

Also,how do you access the id of each "like" using v-for in my view file(unlike button),so I can get the value of like id and pass it to the larval api?

```
[
{
"id": 13,
"reply": "thanks everyone",
"user_id": 2,
"topic_id": 1,
"created_at": "2016-04-20 19:36:58",
"updated_at": "2016-04-20 22:15:02",
"likes": [
        {
      "id": 48,
       "user_id": 3,
       "likeable_id": 13,
       "likeable_type": "App\\Comment",
       "created_at": "2016-04-21 22:18:05",
        "updated_at": "2016-04-21 22:18:05"
     }
      ]
   }

Route::delete('/api/likes/{id}', function($id) {
    return App\Like::destroy($id);
});
```

Vue.js

```
 addLikes:function (id, auth_id) {
                this.unlike = true;                 
                this.$http.patch('/api/likes/' + id + '/' + auth_id).then(function(response) {
                    this.fetchComment(topic_id)
                }, function(response) {
                    return response;
                })                       
            },

     unLike:function(id) {
        this.$http.delete('/api/likes/' + id).then(function (response) {

                 this.fetchComment(topic_id)
                  }, function(response) {

                      return response;
               })

        },
```

I am a noob,so I'm sorry if the question is unclear.Thanks for your help

Comment: Asking question does not make you a noob. A noob will take a part of code without trying to understand it

Comment: I would prefer to have a single button, and a function `toggleLike()`, and also toggle the css class `liked`. the method would first toggle a bollean variable, and then, according to that value, make the proper http request.